# How to reorder date axis in descending order ggplot2

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, gantt-chart

`I'm creating a gantt chart.

If I reorder by ascending date, the chart plots fine, but I'd like to follow gantt chart convention and have the tasks plotted on the y axis by the x axis date in descending order. If I reorder in descending order I get the error message:

Error in `geom_line()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `-.Date`:
! unary - is not defined for "Date" objects
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

> ```
> `
> ```
>
> ```
> ##create dataframe## 
> gantt <- data.frame(Tasks = c('Refine analysis plan', 'Retrieve data', 'Identify cases using SNOMED    codes and study start/end dates', 
>                              'Retrieve clinical and referral events', 'Retrieve covariate data',
>                              'Table of cohort characteristics and outcome frequencies','Age and gender    distribution of incident cases (fig1)','Age and gender distribution of prevalent cases (fig2)',
>                              'Prepare and submit abstract','PPIE work 2',
>                              'Frequency of referrals (staff) (fig3)','Frequency of 2care referrals (staff) (fig4)','Frequency of 2care referrals (diagnosis category) (fig5)',
>                              'Descriptive paper draft for coauthor review',
>                              'Regression analysis of predictors 1',
>                              'Regression analysis of predictors 2',
>                              'Regression analysis of predictors 3',
>                              'Modelling paper draft for coauthor review','conference','Modelling paper draft for coauthor review',
>                              'Submit papers to BJGP','Respond to reviewer comments','PPIE work 3'),
> start.date = as.Date(c("2022-11-01", "2022-11-14", "2022-11-16",
>                                 "2022-11-18", "2022-12-01", 
>                        "2023-01-02","2023-01-09","2023-01-19",
>                        "2023-02-01","2023-02-16",
>                        "2023-03-01", "2023-03-13", "2023-03-23",
>                        "2023-04-03",
>                        "2023-05-01", "2023-05-15", "2023-05-25",
>                        "2023-06-01",
>                        "2023-07-03","2023-07-18","2023-07-21",
>                        "2023-08-01","2023-08-01")),
> end.date = as.Date(c("2022-11-14", "2022-11-16", "2022-11-17",
>                      "2022-11-30", "2022-12-16", 
>                      "2023-01-06","2023-01-18","2023-01-31",
>                      "2023-02-15","2023-02-28",
>                      "2023-03-10", "2023-03-22", "2023-03-31",
>                      "2023-04-28",
>                      "2023-05-12", "2023-05-24", "2023-05-30",
>                      "2023-06-30",
>                      "2023-07-17","2023-07-20","2023-07-31",
>                      "2023-08-31","2023-08-31")),
> task_type = c("Planning","Data preparation","Data preparation",
>                                   "Data preparation","Data preparation","Data description","Data visualisation",
>                                   "Data visualisation","Dissemination & communication","Patient & public involvement and engagement",
>                                   "Data visualisation","Data visualisation","Data visualisation",
>                                   "Dissemination & communication","Data analysis/modelling","Data analysis/modelling","Data analysis/modelling",
>                                   "Dissemination & communication","Dissemination & communication","Dissemination & communication",
>                                   "Dissemination & communication","Dissemination & communication","Patient & public involvement and engagement"))
>
> gantt$duration<-gantt$end.date - gantt$start.date
>
> gantt$name
> gantt$Tasks <- factor( gantt$Tasks , ordered = TRUE )
>
> #create gantt chart
> mgantt <- gantt%>%
> tidyr::pivot_longer(col = c(start.date,end.date))
>
>
> pl <- ggplot(mgantt, aes(x = value, y = reorder(Tasks,-value), colour = task_type ))
> pl <- pl + geom_line( alpha = 0.5, size = 7)
> pl <- pl + theme_bw()
> pl <- pl + labs(title = "Gantt Chart")
> pl <- pl + labs(x = "Month")
> pl <- pl + labs(y = "Tasks")
> pl <- pl + theme(legend.position = "bottom")
> pl <- pl + scale_x_date(name = "Month"
> date_labels = "%b%y"
> date_breaks = "1 month"
> minor_breaks = "1 day")
> pl
> ```
>
> `

Answer (score 0):

You can `reorder` by `-as.numeric(value)`:

```r
ggplot(mgantt, aes(x = value, y = reorder(Tasks, -as.numeric(value)), 
                   colour = task_type )) +
  geom_line( alpha = 0.5, size = 7) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(title = "Gantt Chart") +
  labs(subtitle = "Foot & ankle problems in children: CPRD cohort study") +
  labs(x = "Month") +
  labs(y = "Tasks") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  scale_x_date(name = "Month",
               date_labels = "%b%y",
               date_breaks = "1 month",
               minor_breaks = "1 day")
```

[image]